# Multiple LEFT JOIN in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete, jet

I have the following query, which works for MySQL:

```
DELETE `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4` FROM
`test1` LEFT JOIN `test2` ON test2.qid = test1.id
LEFT JOIN test3 ON test3.tid = test2.id
LEFT JOIN test4.qid = test1.id
WHERE test1.id = {0}
```

But it doesn't work for MS Access. I've tried to add parentheses around the `LEFT JOIN`, but it gives me syntax error in FROM clause.
So how should this query look in order to work in MS Access?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Access DELETE requires a star (*): `DELETE * FROM ...`

In addition, the joins must be nested by using parentheses:

```
DELETE test1.*, test2.*, test3.*, test4.*
FROM
    (
      (
        test1 
        LEFT JOIN test2 ON test1.qid = test2.id
      )
      LEFT JOIN test3 ON test2.tid = test3.id
    )
    LEFT JOIN test4 ON test1.qid = test4.id
WHERE test1.id = {0}
```

This is specific to Access (Jet) SQL.

Comment: Though I have my doubts about {0} :)

Comment: Oh thanks, and I see that I've missed the `test4 ON` part in the last join.

Comment: Probably he wants to replace it using `String.Format(sql, some_id);`, if he is using C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Yes, it's `string.Format`. Doesn't really matter here anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample select statement on three tables with left joins:

```
SELECT 
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.field1 = Table2.field2) 
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table2.field2 = Table3.field3;
```

Your deleted statement:

```
DELETE test1.*, test2.*, test3.*, test4.* 
FROM
((test1 LEFT JOIN test2 ON test2.qid = test1.id)
LEFT JOIN test3 ON test3.tid = test2.id)
LEFT JOIN test4.qid = test1.id)
WHERE (((test1.id) = [SomeParameter]));
```