# Access SQL Inner join 3 tables without like field

Tags: mysql, inner-join

First off, I am pretty sure my answer is here: [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

but after two weeks, I give up.

- Table AssemLines Fields ID, AssemID, ItemID, ItemQty, ServiceID, ServiceQty
- Table Items Fields ItemID, ItemName, ItemDesc
- Table Services Fields ServiceID, ServiceName, ServiceDesc

AssemLines sample data:

```
ID   -   AssemID   -   ItemID  -   ItemQty -  ServiceID   -  ServiceQty
1           1            12          102                        
2           1            62          15                              
3           1                                    3              45
4           2                                    6              90
5           2            23           5
```

Desired Query result:

```
AssemID   -   ItemName     -   ItemQty     -   ServiceName    -   ServiceQty
1               2" tube         102                          
1               3" tube         15
1                                                 Weld               45
2                                                 Saw                90
2               1" tube          5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit this to remove the `-----` so the columns align properly with the fixed-width font? I don't want to make assumptions about what columns are null/empty and it is quite difficult to tell what's what right now. Afterward, highlight and ctl-k or use the `{}` toolbar button to format back to fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just want to replace id's with proper names looked up in other tables. So the most basic join should work:

```
SELECT a.AssemID, i.ItemName, a.ItemQty, s.ServiceName, a.ServiceQty
FROM AssemLines a
LEFT JOIN Items i
  ON a.ItemID = i.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Services s
  ON a.ServiceID = s.ServiceID
```

Comment: Yes, I just want to pull the name at this point. For some reason the above results in Syntax error in FROM clause. I also tried 

[SELECT a.AssemID, i.ItemName, a.ItemQty, s.ServiceName, a.ServiceQty
FROM AssemLines a
   INNER JOIN Items i
        ON a.ItemID = i.ItemID
   INNER JOIN Services s
        ON a.ServiceID = s.ServiceID;] Resulted in same error. Also, can't figure out how to format this comment like the above comment.

Comment: Ms Access just Says "Syntax error in From clause" looks like it highlights the first JOIN behind the message window.

Comment: I put it back exactly your way. Ms Access Says: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'a.ItemID = i.ItemID LEFT JOIN Services s ON a.ServiceID = s.ServiceI'.

Not sure why it cuts off that last "D"

Comment: You have tagged your question `mysql` which is not exactly the same thing as Ms Access. However this is standard SQL that should work in Ms Access too, just make sure you have the same table and column names.

Comment: OK it works, just have to use the foremating found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581838/multiple-left-join-in-access